# Firestore google.cloud.Timestamp parsing

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When i receive firestore DocumentSnapshot field(which is timestamp) with:

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = message.getPayload().getDocumentSnapshot();
Object o = snapshot.get("fieldName);
```

everything works fine and Object o is instantiated with real data `Thu Jan 10 00:00:00 CET 2019`

But when i try to receive the field as google.cloud.Timestamp:

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = message.getPayload().getDocumentSnapshot();
Timestamp ts = snapshot.getTimestamp("fieldName");
```

or `Timestamp ts = (Timestamp) snapshot.get("fieldName");`
it fails with error `java.util.Date cannot be cast to com.google.cloud.Timestamp`

Could someone clarify this behavior and how should i access ad retrieve google.cloud.Timestamp object from DocumentSnapshot? Im having this problem only with Timestamp object, every other type parses normally.

EDIT, adding more code:

Accessing firestore:

```
    @Bean
    public FirestoreGateway registerFirestoreGateway(FirestoreGatewayProperties properties) throws IOException {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(properties.getFirestoreConfiguration());
        InputStream configuration = resource.getInputStream();

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(configuration))
                .setDatabaseUrl(properties.getDatabaseUrl())
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        return new FirestoreGateway(FirestoreClient.getFirestore());
    }
```

Firestore snapshot listener:

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void listenToRequestCommands() {
    firestoreConnection.listCollections().forEach(collectionReference -> {
        collectionReference
                .document(properties.getFirestoreCommand())
                .addSnapshotListener((snapshot, e) -> {
                            Object o = snapshot.get("timestamp");
                            Timestamp ts = (Timestamp) snapshot.get("timestamp");
                        }
                );
    });
}
```

> **Object** **o** parses normally to right value, while **Timestamp** **ts** for the
>   same event throws "**java.util.Date cannot be cast to
>   com.google.cloud.Timestamp**"

Timestamp field definition in database:

[image]

Comment: Please add the entire code that you are using to get the data.

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry for waiting so long for response, i added full implementation for firestore connection, and firestore listener.

Comment: Please also add your database structure to see it more clearly.

Comment: @AlexMamo added picture with firestore structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> java.util.Date cannot be cast to com.google.cloud.Timestamp

Because in your database the *timestamp* property is of type `Date` and **not** `Timestamp`. There is no way in Java to cast an object of type [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to an object of type [com.google.firebase.Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) because there is no inheritance relationship between them.

To solve this, you need to get that property as `Date`, using the following line of code:

```
Date timestamp = snapshot.getDate("timestamp");
```

**Edit:**

When you are setting a field to be of type timestamp, you are setting it as [Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), which is apart of another package. See, `class Timestamp extends Date`. So a timestamp object **is-a** Date, because it inherits from the [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class.

As a conclusion, the [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) class from the `com.google.firebase` package is different from the [Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class from the `java.sql` package, which in terms is different from the [Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Timestamp.html) class that exists within `java.security` package.

**Edit2:**

According to your comment, when using:

```
(java.util.Date) snapshot.get("timestamp");
```

It means that the object that is returned by `snapshot.get("timestamp")` is casted to `Date`, which basically is the same thing. With other words, you tell the compiler that whatever the object that is returned, consider it a `Date` object. And it works because the type of your property in the database is `Date` and **not** `Firebase Timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks for help, can you just clarify to me how come my field is of type Date and not Timestamp when in firestore i defined my field as Timestamp? (provided the picture in question).

Comment: The answer above doesn't seem to work, **snapshot.getDate("timestamp");** also fails with the same exception as **snapshot.getTimestamp("timestamp");**.

Comment: The only solution that managed to work was: `(java.util.Date) snapshot.get("timestamp");`. NOTE: `(Timestamp) snapshot.get("timestamp")` also fails with same exception. I've noticed in implementation of `com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.getDate()` is parsed from **Timestamp** with following code: `return ((Timestamp) get(field)).toDate();`  - which produces the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin solution that work for me:

```
val timestamp: Date = document.getDate("timestamp") as Date
```